# Convergence of Fixed Point Iteration when $|g'(x_*)| = 1$

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

If $x_*$ is a fixed point of a continuously differentiable function $g$, what can we say about the convergence of the fixed-point iteration method $x_{n+1} = g(x_n)$ when $|{g'(x_*)}| = 1$?

I know that for $|{g'(x_*)}| = S$ for $S < 1$, fixed-point iteration will converge for some sufficiently close initial guess $x_0$. We can also extend/generalize this with the contraction mapping theorem.

But what steps should I take if I want to determine if the method will converge when $|{g'(x_*)}| = 1$?

As an example, consider $x_{n+1} = g(x_n)$ where $g(x) = \frac{x}{2} + \frac{1}{x^3}$, $x_0 = 1$.
We know that $x_* = 2^\frac{1}{4}$ is a fixed point of $g$, and that $g'(x_*) = -1$.

I read [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3959470/fixed-point-iteration-method-x-n1-gx-n-doubt) that $|g'(x_*)| = 1$ and $|g'(x_*)| < 1$ almost everywhere near $x_*$ is sufficient but not necessary for convergence given a sufficiently close initial guess. However, in this case, $|g'(x_*)| > 1$ for $x < x_*$ and $|g'(x_*)| < 1$ for $x > x_*$.

Comment: One sufficient condition is firmly non expansive operator